# How to get leading 0 on excel export in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have faced a problem with leading 0 while exporting data in jquery excel exports.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNxHT.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
  I used the below code to resolve these issues.

     <script>
        var _load_ePinreport_lst = {};
        _load_ePinreport_lst.init = function()
        {
            $('#ePin_Report_List').DataTable({
                responsive:true,
                "aaSorting":[],
                stateSave: true,
                "ajax": pathname+'ePin-report/jsondata',
                dom:'Bfrtip',
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "ep_id" },
                    { "data": "store_id" },
                    { "data": "store_name" },
                    { "data": "employee_uid" },
                    { "data": "employee_name" },
                    { "data": "opus_id" },
                    { "data": "item_description" },
                    { "data": "opus_transaction_date" },
                    { "data": "opus_transaction_num" },
                    { "data": "opus_invoice_num" },
                    { "data": "customer_name" },
                    { "data": "mobile_num" },
                    { "data": "opus_amount" },
                    { "data": "rq4_amount" },
                    { "data": "difference" },
                    { "data": "ocomment" },
                    { "data": "upload_date" },
                    { "data": "rq_number" },
                    { "data": "store_comment" },
                    { "data": "submitted_by" },
                    { "data": "submitted_on" },

                ],
                dom:'Bfrtip',
                lengthMenu:[[10, 25, 50, -1],
                    ['10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show All']],
                buttons:[
                    {
                    extend: 'pageLength'
                    },
                    $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        title: 'Epin Reports List'
                    }),
                ],
            });
        }


        var buttonCommon = {
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function(data, column, row, node) {
                    if (row == 1) {
                        return row === 1 ? "\0" + data : data;
                    }
                    else {
                        return data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

        </script>
```